# Is editing a very old answer of one's own OK?

Tags: discussion, editing

One of my old answers has been nagging at me — probably too much time for thought during the pandemic.  It needs expansion, not so much with the English but about the context, which is archaic Greek sculpture.

The answer was **archaic smile**, which IMO was 100% the correct answer, or at least better than any of the alternatives (e.g., **smirk**). I'm not aiming for points, just to get this off my mind.  The edit would be a few sentences, not an essay.

Would this edit be OK, or should I just discipline myself to let this go?

Comment: Why wouldn't you edit it to improve it? That's one of the foundational bits of the Stack Exchange model; the information here is maintained and updated so that it is a reference instead of a forum where each person's question gets answered individually with a "single-use" answer.

Comment: I think I got a badge for it before, or something like that.

Comment: The risk is that by editing it you will have potentially changed your answer to something the upvoters no longer agree with.

Comment: To add to @ColleenV’s comment: There are some Q&A sites that seem to have a culture, if not explicit rules, that the past is past and should be left alone. Stack Exchange is not like that: new answers to old questions, and new edits to old posts, are always acceptable if they are intrinsically beneficial.

Comment: I see no real justification for editing / expanding the existing answer. It includes the salient points from a definition, together with a Wikipedia link to a more complete description of the meaning and origin, *and* a link a real-world usage example. What else needs to be said?

Comment: @GArthurBrown - You can change your vote if it's edited.

Comment: @KannE Then we'd need to receive notifications every time a post we've voted on is edited.

Answer (score 21):

Go, make your posts better! The people deserve the best posts!

There are only a few cases where you *shouldn't* edit to improve an old post (neither of which seems relevant here):

- You're replacing the content instead of building on it (for example, on a single word request, deleting the original word you suggested and replacing it). Nondestructive edits are fine, as is posting new answers when appropriate.
- You've already edited a lot of old posts within a very short period (like more than 10 posts). You should allow other posts to have a chance to be seen on the homepage. In this case, you should come back another time and do your other edits then.

Comment: Non-destructive edits as in non-destructive testing in engineering?